# How cand I create irregular-shaped buttons in C++?

Tags: .net, c++, button

I need to do a map of Europe, and have buttons for each country.
I would really appreciate any sort of help :)

Comment: C++ and .NET? Can you let us know which framework you are using to create this application?

Comment: C++ does not run on the CLR (.NET). Do you mean C++/CLI?

Comment: You can't make buttons in C++ per se. You make buttons with GUI frameworks. Which one are you using

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you display the map of europe as a picture and use a mask image to map pixels to countries. When the user clicks on the map, you check the mask image for the index (color) of the corresponding country.

Irregular-shaped buttons can only be achieved by faking them.